# GWT - I need a piece of text marked up like a link and clickable

Tags: html, css, gwt

I need to have a piece of text, which looks like a link but actually only calls a handler when clicked. I've first wanted to use an `Anchor` for that but most website say to not use an anchor if it doesn't have a href, i.e. point to a URL.

So, what's the (semantically) correct way to do this in GWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a label and style it like an anchor

```
<g:Label ui:field="theLabelName" />
```

Comment: AFAIK in IE6 :hover pseudoclass works only for A elements with HREF attrubute defined, so he will need to also write mouse over/mouse out handlers to switch css styles.

Comment: I just block IE6 users telling them to upgrade their browsers for their own security, been doing it for over three years now and haven't had any complaints.
The amount of dev time saved is well worth the loss of one or two customers who insist on using IE6.

Comment: Unless your application is used by a corporation which is already during migration to IE7 and 30% of users still have IE6...

Comment: Luckily the only corporations I had to deal with using IE6 upgraded after I explained to them the cost-saving benefits of building a turn-key application using the latest cutting edge WEB2 technology and how this technology is crippled by outdated browsers - it's like putting dirty oil in your Lamborghini's petrol tank instead of high grade fuel.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fire a history event, use the Hyperlink widget http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html

If you just want to fire a random event.. not related to history, use a label like Jan mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

new HTML("My Clickable Text");
Then add the click handler to the HTML